# How to create IPA file from visual studio for Xamarin Forms project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have `Xamarin.Forms` project Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 10 PC. *My VS connected to mac machine over the network*. I want to create IPA file from Xamarin forms project. In Google there is no single article available for this.

How can I create IPA file from Windows machine?

I have few additional doubts

- Is it possible to release app to App Store from Windows machine only or I need to use Mac physically
- If I need to use Mac then for which steps while releasing app to App Store
- We are releasing app to App Store using Application Loader or Xcode, Can we do it from Windows machine.
- Can we access Xcode from VS in order to release app to App Store
- If I want to connect real device(to visual studio as targeted device) to create IPA file do I need to connect it in Mac or PC(Via USB cable) in order to get in VS PC
- To create IPA file do we need Mac machine connection

Thank you.

Comment: Somethings you can do on VS4W, some on VS4M (it really depends upon your workflow) Per the docs: "Visual Studio 2017 does not currently support the Archive for Publishing workflow found in Visual Studio for Mac." : Otherwise it is a start to finish doc for Store publishing via Archiving:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows

Comment: There are other "workflows" are available, Xamarin used to directly support `fastline` for iOS|Android as a workflow before Google acquired them, and of course it still works. Microsoft leans toward recommending Azure AppCenter as its deployment workflow. But just about an iOS publishing workflow can be made to work if you sub in `MBBuild` cmd/options for `xcodebuild` cmd/options. Mac access is required, but for most workflows you only need an `ssh` connection as you can do everything without a UI.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Long story short, to build an .ipa, [choose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows#build-and-submit-your-app) `AppStore (or Ad-Hoc, Release) | iPhone` as solution configuration and build the project. After build, you'll find the .ipa file in project's output directory (for example, bin\AppStore). Of course, you have to have corresponding provisioning profiles configured in Xcode but this is another question. More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store).

> Is it possible to release app from Windows machine only or I need to use Mac physically

You need an active connection to macOS to build your .ipa from Windows. And you need to upload the first build from macOS with Application Loader. Uploading can be done either physically from macOS or remotely but not within Visual Studio.

> If I need to use Mac then for which steps while releasing app to App Store

The same as above. You need macOS connection for compilation (building .ipa) and for uploading your *first* build (.ipa) to App Store Connect. Subsequent uploads could be done without macOS.

> We are releasing app to App Store using Application Loader or Xcode, Can we do it from Windows machine.

Publishing a release can also be done using services like [App Center](https://appcenter.ms). However, the [first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/apple#pre-requisites) build should be submitted by Application Loader from macOS.

> Can we access Xcode from VS in order to release app to App Store

No. Visual Studio uses Xcode for building process. Publishing to App Store Connect directly from Visual Studio is not possible for now.

> If I want to connect real device(to visual studio as targeted device) to create IPA file do I need to connect it in Mac or PC(Via USB cable) in order to get in VS PC

You need to connect your device to Mac. However, to build an .ipa, you don't need any iOS device connected.

> To create IPA file do we need Mac machine connection

Again, yes, you do. Compiling, building, and making an .ipa file are the same things in this context.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to release app from Windows machine only or I need to
>   use Mac physically

You will need Application Loader which ships with XCode to submit your IPA to Apple but you can generate the release IPA directly on windows too.

> If I need to use Mac then for which steps We are releasing app to App
>   Store using Application Loader or Xcode, Can we do it from Windows
>   machine. Can we access Xcode from VS in order to release app If I want
>   to connect real device to create IPA file do I need to connect it in
>   Mac in order to get in VS PC

Visual Studio 2017 does not currently support the Archive for Publishing workflow found in Visual Studio for Mac. But you can still generate the IPA and then send it to Apple from a Mac machine later on.

Check the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog on (How to create *.ipa file in Xamarin Forms) :

https://xamarindevelopervietnam.wordpress.com/2016/05/12/how-to-create-ipa-file-in-xamarin-forms/

However I would also prefer you to look into CD CI. Continuous Development and Continuous Integration system. This will help you not only to build the .apk and .ipa for your xamarin projects but also provides you the efficient way of build distribution.

There are several tools available based on your version control. Please check these links :

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/continuous-integration-for-ios-apps-with-visual-studio-team-services/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ci/intro-to-ci

There is a video illustration of doing this in visual studio :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9cOCEuuEOE

Answer (score 2):

> My VS connected to mac machine over the network. I want to create IPA file from Xamarin forms project. In Google, there is no single article available for this.

I think there is an extensive guide that helps you do the exact thing by Microsoft which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows).

> Is it possible to release an app to App Store from Windows machine only or I need to use Mac physically.

By this, if you mean that, do you need a mac's connection then yes a connection to the mac is mandatory, the first build from should be from macOS with Application Loader. But the application can also be uploaded to apple from a windows machine, using a mac here in my knowledge is not mandatory. (Personally, I have never done it from a windows machine though)

> If I need to use Mac then for which steps while releasing an app to App Store

Having an active mac connection and [provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/index?tabs=windows) and [publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows) should do the trick.

> We are releasing an app to App Store using Application Loader or Xcode, Can we do it from Windows machine.

There are multiple products that provide services for uploading the IPA directly to Appstore but in my knowledge, the first time should be Application loader with macOS.

> Can we access Xcode from VS in order to release an app to App Store.

The answer for this would be a NO! for now.

> If I want to connect real device(to visual studio as targeted device) to create IPA file do I need to connect it in Mac or PC(Via USB cable) in order to get in VS PC

Of course to the MAC system since VS uses X-Code for its build process, but note that it's always better to create an IPA by selecting the Selected Platform as `Any CPU`. Secondly. while earlier there was a requirement that your mac should have a device connected to it(While archiving from windows), I do not think it still exists.

> To create IPA file do we need Mac machine connection

Yes, it is mandatory to have a mac system connected as VS uses XCode to bundle everything and iOS is closed source hence has a dependency on the MAC.

Goodluck

Feel free to revert in case of queries.